# Dropping a part of the URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a setup where I route all requests for /upload/* to Rails. Using the blog example, I want `somedomain.com/upload/article/new` to be treated as `somedomain.com/article/new` by Rails. I ended up with the following.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"
  scope 'upload' do
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

**nginx.conf**

```
location /upload/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }
```

It works, but you can clearly see the same code written twice right next to each other.
I was wondering if there's a more proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a helper method:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  def uploadable
    # yield first outside the scope so that your helper methods
    # generate urls without "/upload" prefix (since you don't want it anyway)
    yield
    scope "upload" do
      yield
    end
  end

  uploadable do
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end
```

You can also try making "upload" part optional:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(/upload)" do
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried both and found the 2nd options works perfectly. The 1st one, however, has an issue where links are set to somedomain.com/article/1 and not somedomain.com/upload/article/1 as expected. Also, I think you forgot to add root "articles#index" on both options.

Comment: if you actually need `/upload` part then put the first `yield` after the `scope`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails.application.routes.draw do
root "articles#index"

resources :articles do
resources :comments
end

scope 'upload', controller: 'articles', as: 'upload' do
resources :articles, path: '' do
resources :comments
end
end
end

I removed the duplication of the resources :articles do ... end block outside the 'upload' scope.

Within the 'upload' scope, I used the controller option to specify that requests should be handled by the 'articles' controller.

I used the as: 'upload' option to assign a name to this scope, making the path more readable.